# Calculate AUC and diagnostic accuracy for each outcome after mlogit in Stata

Tags: stata, logistic-regression, roc, multinomial

I wonder if there are Stata codes available to assess the model performance of a multinomial logistic model such as discrimination (AUC) for each outcome and diagnostic accuracy.

I am trying to fit a multinomial model for four outcomes using mlogit in Stata.

The command 'mlogitroc' was tried, but it doesn't give the AUC or ROC for each evaluated outcome.

Comment: I'd ask on Statalist where many more people using this will read the question.  Are these procedures defined in the literature or implemented in other software?

Comment: Thank You Nick. I did notice from the literature that these can be calculated by SPSS and R, although the exact codes were not shown.

Comment: Please do not cross-post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/615741/36682

Comment: Also you're unlikely to get a good answer with so little details. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your chance to get an answer.